# Delete a record from firebase realtime database

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I use angular version 5.0.0 and angularfire2 version 5.0.0-rc.3.
When I want to delete a record from firebase database, I can remove the record but I also get an error and the error message is:

> Firebase Storage: Invalid argument in `child` at index 0: Expected string.

Here we can see more details on chrome's console:

[image]

And this is my service (firebase.service.ts):

```js
@Injectable()
export class FirebaseService {

  listings: AngularFireList<any[]>;

  constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) {
    this.listings = this.db.list('listings') as AngularFireList<any[]>;
  }

  deleteListing(id: any) {
    return this.listings.remove(id);
  }
}
```

And this is how I use it in the component (navbar.component.ts):

```js
  deleteListing() {
    this.firebaseService.deleteListing(this.id).then(() => {
      this.router.navigate(['listings']);
    });
  }
```

And the whole project is available in GitHub repo: [here](https://github.com/peymannj/AngularFirebaseCrud)

Comment: (dont know angular at all). Problem here may be angular trying to rerender template with non-existent data after removing, before navigating away.

Navigate before removal (lame) or use some angular-specific magic.

Comment: The error message seems to indicate that the error comes from Firebase Storage: `Firebase Storage: Invalid argument in `child` at index 0:`

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen -blunder-, you're totally right!

Comment: it `this.id` a string?

Comment: @ewizard I tried with type any and string and the result is same and i have error.

Comment: @entio I use Then()  it means that function should wait for the complete result and then navigate.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Yes, But can it be a bug in AngularFire2 ?

Comment: what does `this.id` represent exactly?

Comment: Without seeing the relevant code, it is impossible to say what the cause of the problem is. Please edit your question to show the [minimum, compete code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Given the error message, that code likely just needs to use the Cloud Storage for Firebase SDK (and possibly AngularFire).